# VB.NET WPF correctly populate datagrid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I am looking to pull the data in from the table then add it to a list then use that list to populate the datagrid; however, when doing this I get the wrong population on my grid although I know for a fact that I am accessing the correct records in my loop.

Here is my code:

```
    Public Class Room

    Private _RoomNumber As String
    Public Property RoomNumber As String
        Get
            Return _RoomNumber
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _RoomNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _PatientName As String
    Public Property PatientName As String
        Get
            Return _PatientName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _PatientName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Physician As String
    Public Property Physician As String
        Get
            Return _Physician
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Physician = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Nurse As String
    Public Property Nurse As String
        Get
            Return _Nurse
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _Nurse = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _SchedTime As String
    Public Property SchedTime As String
        Get
            Return _SchedTime
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _SchedTime = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ArrivalTime As String
    Public Property ArrivalTime As String
        Get
            Return _ArrivalTime
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ArrivalTime = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _ES As String
    Public Property ES As String
        Get
            Return _ES
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _ES = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Private Sub loadPage() Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Dim newList As New List(Of Room)
    newList = getData()
    MedDayDataGrid.ItemsSource = newList
End Sub

Private Function getData() As List(Of Room)
    Dim connection As New ODBCConnection() //Left this out for obv reasons
    connection.Open()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT visit.visit_name, visit.visit_admit_date, visit.visit_id, ip_visit_1.ipv1_room FROM visit INNER JOIN ip_visit_1 ON visit.visit_id=ip_visit_1.ipv1_num WHERE visit.visit_disch_date = '0001-01-01' AND ip_visit_1.ipv1_room LIKE 'MDH%' ORDER BY ip_visit_1.ipv1_room"
    Dim myCommand As New OdbcCommand(query, connection)

    Dim myRoom As New Room
    Dim myList As New List(Of Room)

    Dim myReader As OdbcDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    While myReader.Read()
        myRoom.RoomNumber = myReader.GetString(3)
        myRoom.PatientName = myReader.GetString(0)
    End While

    myReader.Close()

    connection.Close()
    connection = Nothing

    Return myList
End Function
```

The data returned is displaying the last recorded added to the list 20 times on my grid instead of showing each of the 20 individual rooms that were added to the list in the getData() function. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't see how you get any data displayed at all.  In `getData`, you don't seem to be adding anything to `myList`.  Did you miss some code in the question?  Assuming there is an `Add` in there somewhere, your problem is likely that you are not creating a new `Room` for each row, and are reusing the same instance for each row - thereby adding the same instance to the list 20 times, with the values being overwritten each time - resulting in the values for the last row being set for all items, since they are actually the same object.

Comment: Sorry I was debugging and accidentally left my add out. My add was in the while loop with myreader.read(). Your answer was exactly what I needed. I was not creating a new instance of room each time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `Room` instance for each row returned by the query, and add that to the `List`, e.g.

```
Private Function getData() As List(Of Room)
    Dim connection As New ODBCConnection() //Left this out for obv reasons
    connection.Open()
    Dim query As String = "SELECT visit.visit_name, visit.visit_admit_date, visit.visit_id, ip_visit_1.ipv1_room FROM visit INNER JOIN ip_visit_1 ON visit.visit_id=ip_visit_1.ipv1_num WHERE visit.visit_disch_date = '0001-01-01' AND ip_visit_1.ipv1_room LIKE 'MDH%' ORDER BY ip_visit_1.ipv1_room"
    Dim myCommand As New OdbcCommand(query, connection)

    Dim myList As New List(Of Room)

    Dim myReader As OdbcDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    While myReader.Read()
        Dim myRoom As New Room
        myRoom.RoomNumber = myReader.GetString(3)
        myRoom.PatientName = myReader.GetString(0)
        myList.Add(myRoom)
    End While

    myReader.Close()

    connection.Close()
    connection = Nothing

    Return myList
End Function
```